# Vmware ESXi 4.1 iSCSI MPIO - What is wrong with these steps?

Tags: vmware-esxi, storage-area-network, network-storage, datastore

I'm trying to add another vm host to our SAN and I don't have good notes on how I got this working last time. (dumb mistake) I've pieced my steps together from a script I had for our production environment.

```
esxcfg-vswitch.pl -a vSwitch2

esxcfg-vswitch.pl -m 9000 vSwitch2

esxcfg-vswitch.pl -A iSCSI1 vSwitch2
esxcfg-vswitch.pl -A iSCSI2 vSwitch2

esxcfg-vmknic.pl -a -i xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -n 255.255.255.0 -m 9000 iSCSI1
esxcfg-vmknic.pl -a -i xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -n 255.255.255.0 -m 9000 iSCSI2

vicfg-iscsi.pl --swiscsi --enable

(go in and edit NIC Teaming - Move adaptors "extra" adapter to Unused for each vmk)

esxcli swiscsi nic add -n vmk1 -d vmhba38
esxcli swiscsi nic add -n vmk2 -d vmhba38
```

Once I do this I can add an address for dynamic discovery and it will find static discovery locations, but I can't add any datastores. any ideas?

Comment: are you using chap credentials on your iSCSI LUNs?

Comment: No, turns out I was dumb and on my testing LUN i didn't enable simultaneous connections from initators with different IQN names, on the LUN and I had another Host connected to it. The log files told me what I needed to fix, I should have looked there sooner.

Comment: A nitpick, if I may: best practice is to have two vswitches, one for each iSCSI VLAN, then for each vswitch connect a single pnic and create a single vmknic.

Comment: @ynguldyn why would you use iscsi vlans if you have a completely separate Storage network with Redundant switches? just in case of a brocast flood or something along those lines?

Comment: The vmknics used for iSCSI should be placed in different subnets to avoid problems (for example EMC Clariions absolutely hated same subnet initiators, until very recent FLARE versions fixed it). And if you have different subnets, creating VLANs for them is simply good hygiene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was dumb and on my testing LUN i didn't enable simultaneous connections from initators with different IQN names, on the LUN and I had another Host connected to it. The log files told me what I needed to fix, I should have looked there sooner.